# How to fix fatal error openCV: fatal error: 'highgui/highgui.hpp' file not found #include <highgui/highgui.hpp>

Tags: c++, xcode, opencv

I am trying to follow along the Bradski's intro to openCV book. I've installed CMake and the latest version of openCV. I am trying to run the following code that's supposed to take in a png file from the command line

```
#include <highgui/highgui.hpp>
using namespace cv;
int main( int argc, char** argv ) {
  Mat img = imread( argv[0], -1 );
    if( img.empty() ) return -1;
      namedWindow( "Example 2-2", cv::WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
      imshow( "Example 2-2", img );
      waitKey( 0 );
      destroyWindow( "Example 2-2" );
    }
```

I am using XCode. I added all my libraries which includes the highgui library and I added the pathname to my opencv4 folder to header search paths.

Xcode builds without any errors but when I try to run the main.cpp file on the command

line I get the error:

> fatal error: 'highgui/highgui.hpp' file not found
> #include <highgui/highgui.hpp>

I tried everything. I checked my opencv files to make sure highgui.hpp is there and it is.

Comment: wrong include directive. work with documentation. https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d7/dfc/group__highgui.html it says to use `#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>` why would you do this differently?

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz Sorry, forgot to mention that I originally had that include directive but I still get the same error: fatal error: 'opencv2/highgui.hpp' file not found
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>

Comment: then you forgot to tell the compiler where to find the includes. give it an additional include directory, which should be the one for opencv's headers.